# Problem to show single row table in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to show a table in the html using python flask framework. I have two array. One for column heading and another for data record. I am able to show the table perfectly when I have two or more records. However, if I have only one row then table formation is not right. How to fix this problem? Could help me to solve this?
[image]
[image]

**table.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():

    headings = ("name", "role", "salary")
    data = (("rolf", "software engineer", "4500"), ("neu", "civil engineer", "1500"), ("neu", "civil engineer", "1500"))

    return render_template('table2.html', data=data, headings=headings)
```

**table2.html**

```
<table>
<tr>
{% for header in headings %}
       <th>{{ header }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
    {% for cell in row %}
    <td>{{ cell }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to fail with a single record defined incorrectly as:

```
data = (("rolf", "software engineer", "4500")) # incorrect
```

The fix is to include the trailing comma for the outer tuple, which must be done when a tuple contains only one item:

```
data = (("rolf", "software engineer", "4500"),)
```

'Why' can be demonstrated in the python shell:

```
>>> data = (("rolf", "software engineer", "4500"))
>>> data
('rolf', 'software engineer', '4500')
>>> data[0]
'rolf'
>>> # etc ...
... 
>>> data = (("rolf", "software engineer", "4500"),)
>>> data
(('rolf', 'software engineer', '4500'),)
>>> data[0]
('rolf', 'software engineer', '4500')
>>>
```

In the template, a string is reaching the loop: `{% for cell in row %}` where `cell` is each character in that string, instead of an individual item from the inner tuple.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Now, I want make it dynamic (dynamic length of the column). I can easily change the value of the column heading. Next transfer this column 'heading' to html.
 headings = []
 headings.append("name")   
 headings.append("role")    
 
But if I want to chage column data dynamically using an array. it is not working. Could you help to make this dynamic.    
 data = []
 data.append("rolf")
 data.append("software engineer")
 data.append("rolf")
 data.append("software engineer")

Comment: @user1850484 This is probably better posted as a separate question, with an example of the current code you have, alongside the problem description.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584539/problem-to-show-data-dynamically-table-in-python-flask